# How FST constructed in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

During search, Lucene uses FST to match against the terms. Is FST constructed for every search? Or will it be constructed once and stored in the disk? If it is stored, How the changes in the index will be updated in FST?

What about the time and memory required for loading the FST into main memory?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene uses a Log-structured merge-tree like index, for each segment the FST is constructed. in the merge tree, segments are not modified, only merged (and filtered in the process). In the merge FSTs are combined/recreated.

The segments/FSTs are usually memory mapped, depending on if you use MMapDirectoryReader or not.

But this is only from memory and an educated guess.